# Make Button Bounce with CSS3

Tags: html, css, button, css-animations

I am trying to make this button bounce with CSS3

```css
.order {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 1;
  background: green;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="order">Order</div>
```

I would like it to bounce towards the screen (on the Z axis) up and down.

Comment: Try this example https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/yqsayLq8/3/

Comment: Update your link - it's going to a 404

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a keyframe animation to animate the scale ratio and **make your button bounce**:

```css
.order {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 1;
  background: green;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation: bounce .3s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes bounce {
  to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}
```

```html
<div class="order">Order</div>
```

### Iteration count:

If you want to stop the animation after a number of "bounces", you can use `animation-iteration-count` (use an even number of iterations otherwise the animation will snap on the last iteration) :

```css
.order {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 1;
  background: green;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  animation: bounce .3s infinite alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: 8;
}
@keyframes bounce {
  to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}
```

```html
<div class="order">Order</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29006068/3556874), would be the best one to use, still I have a different approach becoz you have already used `position:absolute`.

See this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/yqsayLq8/1/)
 you need to animate height and width for button using keyframe.

```css
.order {
  background: url("http://onestudio.id-staging.com/_BUILD/Dominos/BANNERS/C3%20Digital%20Midweek%20Rescue/Wide%20Skyscraper/images/order.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 1s infinite;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="order"></div>
```

**Edit:**

> To add further, you can also animate left and top to 38px both so the
>   button doesn't look like deviating from original position see this
>   [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/yqsayLq8/4/)

```css
.order {
  background: url("http://onestudio.id-staging.com/_BUILD/Dominos/BANNERS/C3%20Digital%20Midweek%20Rescue/Wide%20Skyscraper/images/order.png") no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1s infinite;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: mymove 0.5s 2;
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 38px;
    top: 38px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="order"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this css

```
.order {
    background:url("http://onestudio.id-staging.com/_BUILD/Dominos/BANNERS/C3%20Digital%20Midweek%20Rescue/Wide%20Skyscraper/images/order.png");
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      top:50px;
      left:50px;
      width: 75px;
      height: 75px;
      z-index:1;
      opacity:1;

}

@keyframes fade {
    from { top:40px;
      left:40px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px; }
    50% { top:50px;
      left:50px;
      width: 75px;
      height: 75px; }
    to { top:40px;
      left:40px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from { top:40px;
      left:40px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px; }
    50% { top:50px;
      left:50px;
      width: 75px;
      height: 75px; }
    to { top:40px;
      left:40px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px; }
}

.blink {
    animation:fade 1000ms infinite;
    -webkit-animation:fade 1000ms infinite;
}
```

try this html

```
<div class="order blink"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can animate(bounce) like following:

**CSS:**

```
.order {
    background:url("http://onestudio.id-staging.com/_BUILD/Dominos/BANNERS/C3%20Digital%20Midweek%20Rescue/Wide%20Skyscraper/images/order.png");
      position: absolute;
      top:50px;
      left:50px;
      width: 75px;
      height: 75px;
      z-index:1;
      opacity:1;
      animation: myfirst 2s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: myfirst 2s infinite; 
}

    @-webkit-@keyframes myfirst {

    0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
   transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
   transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes myfirst {

    0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
   transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
   transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqsayLq8/5/)